# Edit docker run command not to include -v flag

Tags: docker, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to make [grpc-wiremock](https://github.com/Adven27/grpc-wiremock)'s example work: essentially there's this

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 50000:50000 -v $(pwd)/example/proto:/proto -v $(pwd)/example/wiremock:/wiremock adven27/grpc-wiremock
```

command and I'd like to edit its Dockerfile to avoid using volumes but when I try:

```
# https://github.com/Adven27/grpc-wiremock/blob/master/Dockerfile#L12-L13
COPY . /usr/src/java-code/
COPY example/my_proto /usr/src/java-code/proto <--- added line
WORKDIR /usr/src/java-code
```

and then

```
➜  grpc-wiremock git:(master) ✗ docker build -t foo . 
➜  grpc-wiremock git:(master) ✗ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 50000:50000 foo
```

it seems like the service doesn't pick up that `proto` directory:

```
Registered services:
 * grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
# expected to see some new services
```

When I exec into a container, I can see there's `proto` directory and it's not empty but it's still not getting picked up (I was hoping it'll replace `-v $(pwd)/example/my_proto:/proto`):

```
root@44704a7f07ad:/usr/src/java-code# ls
build  build.gradle  Dockerfile  example  gradle  gradle.properties  gradlew  gradlew.bat  LICENSE  proto  README.md  settings.gradle  src
root@44704a7f07ad:/usr/src/java-code# cd proto/
root@44704a7f07ad:/usr/src/java-code/proto# ls
bar.proto foo_folder_with_other_protos
```

How can I edit [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Adven27/grpc-wiremock/blob/master/Dockerfile) to avoid using volumes completely?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to add

```
COPY example/my_proto /proto # instead of /usr/src/java-code/proto
```